# Facebook App - Need Secure URL for Localhost testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I want to test my Facebook Canvas app on Localhost. From old answer (2011) I found here, they just set the Site URL with `http://localhost:3000`. But, now the URL requires `https` to run on Facebook Canvas.

Some of the newer answers (2013) mentioned about disabling `sandbox` mode, but I can't find those options anymore.

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need HTTPS. This is because facebook.com is not served over HTTP anymore and browsers don't allow HTTP content inside HTTPS pages.

But if it is just for development just use a self signed cert and click away the warning that the browser gives you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Never knew there are such thing as self signed cert. Will try it :)